# How to show that the determinant of a special $4 \times 4$ matrix is nonzero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Show that if $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ and at least one is different from $0$, then

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c & d\\ 
b & -a & d &-c \\ 
c & -d & -a &b \\ 
d & c & -b &-a 
\end{vmatrix} \neq 0$$

Comment: What have you done so far? It seems straightforward...

Comment: I do not even know how to start XD.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the determinant of a $4 \times 4$ matrix by expanding along a row or column? If so, just do it! If not... well, then I don't think you're really in a position to be solving the problem.

Comment: I know how to do it but is it not pointless?

Comment: @OvyOvy A more clever solution is using quaternions, see the proof reference of my answer. But still just computing it is not pointless, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need any references or any remotely complicated calculations to show what is required. The matrix is indeed related to quaternion representation, but it is *not* the discussed representation.

First, note that if you factor out $-1$ from 3 last rows of your matrix you will get the skew-symmetric matrix
$$
(-1)\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c & d\\ 
-b & a & -d &c \\ 
-c & d & a &-b \\ 
-d & -c & b &a 
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Now *this is* the representation two other answers refer to. Take this matrix and multiply by its transpose. You will find the diagonal matrix with all four elements on the main diagonal $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)$. Now conclude...

Comment: Can the downvoter explain?

Answer (score 6):

This is a well-known determinant arising from quaternions. It has the value
$$
-(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2.
$$
Over the real numbers the value can only be zero if all of $a,b,c,d$ are zero.

The quaternion algebra $\mathbb{H}$ can be represented as the set of the above $4\times 4$ matrices with the $4$ real parameters $a,b,c,d$.

The determinant has been already calculated by Dickson in [A Matrix Defined by the Quaternion Group](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2971280.pdf), page $245$, in the year $1902$ (three rows differ by a factor of $-1$, so the result there is $+(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$).

Comment: How do you do it?

Comment: Did you try to search for this determinant? Write is a $2\times 2$ blocks, and note that two of them are symmetric, two are skew-symmetric.

Comment: I do not really know how to search for determinants on google.

Comment: Interesting. I have not seen this determinant before.

Comment: +1, but I'd rather say relatively known determinant...

Comment: Well I did not know it XD

Comment: So how do I do it? Or tell me if I can search for it.

Comment: @amWhy I added a reference with a proof.

Comment: @Dietrich  I didn't downvote your answer, but I've deleted my comment and will now upvote $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 4):

There are several references you might find useful.

- [Determinant of block matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices). In particular, for $2\times 2$ real matrices $A,B,C,D$, the following formula holds *WHEN* $CD=DC$,
  $$
  {\displaystyle \det {\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}}=\det(AD-BC).}
  $$ 
  [Here](http://www.ee.iisc.ac.in/new/people/faculty/prasantg/downloads/blocks.pdf) is a proof of this formula.
- The matrix representation of [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Sums_of_four_squares).

---

[Added] To elaborate Artem's answer, here is another way to do it.

Denote the matrix in your question as
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}
a & b & c & d\\ 
b & -a & d &-c \\ 
c & -d & -a &b \\ 
d & c & -b &-a 
\end{matrix}\right).
$$
Then 
$$
AA^t=
\left(\begin{matrix}
a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 
\end{matrix}\right).
$$
Note that
$$
\det(A)^2=\det(A)\det(A^t).
$$

Comment: Ok but that is for a 2x2 determinant. But for 4x4?

Comment: No. Both $A$ and $B$ are $2\times 2$ matrices.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Artem methode but this is a direct methode :

We can assume that $a\neq0$ :
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c & d\\ 
b & -a & d &-c \\ 
c & -d & -a &b \\ 
d & c & -b &-a 
\end{vmatrix} &=&\frac{1}{a}\begin{vmatrix}
a^2 & b & c & d\\ 
ab & -a & d &-c \\ 
ac & -d & -a &b \\ 
ad & c & -b &-a 
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=&  \frac{1}{a}\begin{vmatrix}
a^2 +b^2+c^2+d^2 & b & c & d\\ 
(ab-ab+dc-cd) & -a & d &-c \\ 
(ac-bd-ac+bd) & -d & -a &b \\ 
(ad+cb-bc-ad) & c & -b &-a 
\end{vmatrix}((C_1)+b(C_2)+c(C_3)+d(C_4)\to (C_1) ) \\
&=& \frac{1}{a}\begin{vmatrix}
a^2 +b^2+c^2+d^2 & b & c & d\\ 
0 & -a & d &-c \\ 
0 & -d & -a &b \\ 
0 & c & -b &-a 
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=& \frac{a^2 +b^2+c^2+d^2}{a}\begin{vmatrix}
 -a & d &-c \\ 
 -d & -a &b \\ 
 c & -b &-a 
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=&\frac{a^2 +b^2+c^2+d^2}{a}\left(-a(a^2+b^2)-d(ad-bc)-c(db+ac) \right)\\
&=&\frac{a^2 +b^2+c^2+d^2}{a}\left(-a(a^2+b^2)-ad^2+dbc-cdb-ac^2 \right)\\
&=&\frac{a^2 +b^2+c^2+d^2}{a}\left(-a(a^2+b^2+b^2+c^2) \right)\\
&=& -(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2
\end{eqnarray}